# Объединение двух массивов в третий за исключением значений, которые уже есть

Tags: javascript, массивы

Нужно объединить (создать еще один) два массива в один, но нужно чтобы в объединенном массиве исключались повторения значений, например:

```
let array1 = ['all', 'video', 'image', 'text']
let array2 = ['all', 'video', 'footprints', 'photo']
```

а на выходе получалось:
`arrayAll['all', 'video', 'image', 'text', 'footprints', 'photo']`

Comment: в массивах только строковые значения? или могут быть объекты?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1584370/how-to-merge-two-arrays-in-javascript-and-de-duplicate-items Здесь более чем подробно, нечего добавить :)

Comment: пусть будут просто строковые, если будут вопросы и по объектам я создам соответствующий вопрос.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```js
let array1 = ['all', 'video', 'image', 'text'];
let array2 = ['all', 'video', 'footprints', 'photo'];

let data = {};
array1.concat(array2).forEach(function(item) {
  data[item] = true;
});
let result = Object.keys(data);
console.log(result);
```

Comment: А если количество объединяемых массивов нам неизвестно ?

Comment: @NeedHate "количество ... неизвестно" - вообще никогда?

Comment: Если количество объединяемых массивов динамическое, то можно привести их к итерабельной структуре, например к массиву массивов, а потом так же заполнить объект.

Comment: @Igor, вообще никогда ) Как внесет пользователь, столько разных значений массивов и будет .

Answer (score 1):

```
console.log(Array.from(new Set(array1.concat(array2))))
```

Answer (score 0):

```
console.log([...new Set([...array1,...array2])])
```

Comment: Добавьте немного информации, почему вы считаете,  что это поможет автору вопроса.